# Unary plus (+) against literal string

Tags: c++, string-literals, unary-operator

Today I wrote an expression:

```
"<" + message_id + "@" +  + ">"
                          ^
                          |
                          \____  see that extra '+' here!
```

and got surprised that it actually compiled. (PS `message_id` is a `QString`, it would also work with an `std::string`)

I often do things like that, leave out a variable as I'm working and I expect the compiler to tell me where I'm still missing entries. The final would look something like this:

```
"<" + message_id + "@" + network_domain + ">"
```

Now I'd like to know why the `+` unary operator is valid against a string literal!?

Comment: what type is message_id?

Comment: pointer arithmetic probably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unary `+` can be applied to arithmetic type values, unscoped enumeration values and pointer values because ...

the C++ standard defines it that way, in C++11 §5.3.1/7.

In this case the string literal, which is of type array of `char const`, decays to pointer to `char const`.

It's always a good idea to look at the documentation when one wonders about the functionality of something.

---

“The operand of the unary `+` operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the
result is the value of the argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands.
The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.”

Comment: So the expression `"<" + message_id + "@" +  + ">"` is exactly equivalent to `"<" + message_id + "@" + ">"`

Comment: Could you cite C++11 §5.3.1/7 please?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Actually, I believe it'd be `"<" + message_id + "@"++ ">"`

Comment: @Rapptz, you can test it:)

Comment: @Rapptz ++ does not work against a literal string, plus the last ">" would then generate an error in the expression.

Comment: @AlexisWilke You're right. I'm unsure why the `+ +` is compiling, and this answer really doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Rapptz: C++ follows the "maximum munch" rule where the lexer scans along as long as it has a valid token. The *space* between the two instances of `+` causes the lexer to treat them as two separate tokens. Thus they cannot constitute a `++` operator (and the OP is obviously aware of that, asking about unary `+` he has identified it as such, and only wonders why it can be applied to a literal string).

Comment: @Rapptz: the clause that Alf cites says, "The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of the argument". So the expression `+ ">"` evaluates to `">"`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain it (for me personally), and I don't feel like giving a full fledged answer. The reason is compiles is because `"<" + message_id + "@"` would result in `<test@` is `message_id` is `test`. Then you're left with `message_id + + ">"`, that means that `">"` (which is of type `const char[2]` decays to `const char*` meaning you're left with `message_id + ">"` with `">"` as a `const char*`. The expression wouldn't have worked without `message_id`. That's really all I wanted to know.

Comment: I wonder what was the rationale for allowing unary `+` on pointers. It is not in C, but it is in C++98.

Comment: @Rapptz: yes, `message_id` needs to be in there so that `QString` operator overloads apply for all of the binary `+` operators.  But the question was about the last `+` operator, and Alf's answer explains why that doesn't end up being a syntax error.

Comment: @AndreyT: I don't know, but if it's anywhere then most likely that place is in Bjarne's "Design and Evolution" of C++ book. I don't have, but Jerry Coffin has it. And I believe (but not sure) you'll find him in the C++ lounge. ;-) If I were to *guess* then I would say "for uniform rules". E.g. when I asked Bjarne about the rationale for allowing reference to const to bind to rvalue everywhere, that was the answer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr They're not exactly equivalent. One allows calling an `operator+` that takes an array reference as its argument, the other does not, because unary + has already forced the array-to-pointer conversion.