# Needing help storing functions as variables and printing out the variables

Tags: c++, function, random

I am currently working on a dice rolling program for my CS121 class and this is my code. I am trying to write a function that rolls a 6 sided die and rerolls it when it rolls 1. I want to call that function 3 times and then add the outputs of the functions together. Unfortunately underneath roll2 when I am trying to add it and output it there is a red line and when I hover over it it states "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type. I am stumped so if you could help me find a way around this that would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void diceroll() {
    int result = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
    if (result != 1)
       cout << result << + " ";
    else cout << result << +" ";
}
int main() {

    auto roll1 = diceroll;
    auto roll2 = diceroll;
    auto roll3 = diceroll;



    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is" << endl;
    cout << roll1 + roll2 + roll3;


}
```

Comment: You've defined `void diceroll`, which means the compiler thinks it does not return a value.  The function is also not returning a value - it's just printing one to the console. Change it to return `int` instead, and then `return result;` in the code. Also, in `diceroll`, your `if` statement makes no sense, as both the `if` and `else` do the exact same thing - they both `cout << result << " ";`.

Comment: The `+" "` syntax is worth its own question on Stackoverflow. What in dickens is that? And what is that `if` statement supposed to accomplish? Both `if` and `else` part do exactly the same, identical thing.

Comment: When you used the `auto` keyword, you let the compiler decide what the types of `roll1`, `roll2`, and `roll3` are. If you were expecting them to be integers, define them as integers (e.g. `int roll1 = diceroll;`). This will change your error so that it more accurately describes where the error is located.

Answer (score 6):

Your code sample is not syntactically correct in C++.

Looking at the original code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void diceroll() {
    int result = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
    if (result != 1)
       cout << result << + " ";   /* Hmmm...: why add the '+' ? */
    else cout << result << +" ";  /* Hmmm...: why add the '+' ? */
}
int main() {

    auto roll1 = diceroll;
    auto roll2 = diceroll;
    auto roll3 = diceroll;

    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is" << endl;
    cout << roll1 + roll2 + roll3; /* ERRORS: adding pointers, operator precedence */
}
```

So let's start with the 1st task: a function that rolls a dice and returns its result, with the added requirement that if it rolls a '1', then it must roll again.  in other words, it should never return '1'.

```
int diceroll() {
    int result ;

    do {
        result = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
    } while ( result == 1 ) ;

    return result ;
}
```

Now, let's look at calling this 3 times and outputting the result.

```
int main() {

    /* Option 1: explicit */
    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is" << endl;
    cout << ( diceroll() + diceroll() + diceroll() ) << endl ;

    /* Option 2: using variables containing function pointers */
    auto roll1 = diceroll ; // assigns function pointer
    auto roll2 = diceroll ;
    auto roll3 = diceroll ;
    
    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is" << endl;
    cout << ( roll1() + roll2() + roll3() ) << endl ;

    /* Option 3: In case you were really trying to do this: */
    auto roll1 = diceroll() ; // assigns result of dice roll
    auto roll2 = diceroll() ; // assigns result of dice roll
    auto roll3 = diceroll() ; // assigns result of dice roll

    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is" << endl;
    cout << ( roll1 + roll2 + roll3 ) << endl ;

    return 0 ; /* EXIT_SUCCESS */
}
```

In all cases, remember about bundling your sum inside parentheses, otherwise  you'll get bitten by operator precedence...

Oh, and if you're compiling pre C++11:

```
// ... declare the function pointer type (underneath the 'using namespace std' statement)
typedef int (*diceroll_function_t)() ;

// ... Inside main(): instead of auto roll1 = diceroll 
diceroll_function_t roll1 = diceroll ;
```

Lastly, about the weird:

```
<< + " "
```

Kyle commented below about why that part compiles.  Here is a link that talks about it:

[Unary plus (+) against literal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439442/unary-plus-against-literal-string)

Comment: The `<< +" "` is not an error because the `+` is not the binary + operator in this case, it's the unary + operator and when applied to the string literal forces it to decay into a `const char*`. Ultimately this becomes a no-op since the overloaded `<<` may cause this conversion to happen anyway. This unary + trick is sometimes used to force lambdas to decay into function pointers. That said, there's no reason to have that operator there as it doesn't do anything except confuse the reader.

Answer (score 1):

In `roll1 + roll2 + roll3` you aren't calling your functions, you're doing pointer arithmetic. Add the `()` to your function names to call them.

Comment: OP also needs to `return` a value in the function.

Comment: I think you read the code incorrectly. This isn't the primary problem with the posted code.

Comment: True, but he also needs to call the functions: _I want to call that function 3 times_,

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the job. First we change the return type of `diceroll()` function to `int` so that we can call it in our main function and get the value on the face of the dice. Using an intuitive recursion, I have formulated the function to also print out the value on the face of the dice.

I recommend seeding the rand function using `srand(time(0))` otherwise you will get the same value on the face of the dice everytime you run the programme.

Each diceroll will keep on calling itself till `result` has a value other than 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int diceroll()
{
    int result = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
    cout << result << +" ";
    if (result == 1)
        return diceroll();
    cout << endl;
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int r1 = diceroll(), r2 = diceroll(), r3 = diceroll();
    cout << "The total of the 3 numbers is: "
         << (r1 + r2 + r3) << endl;
}
```