# what is this + before u8 string literal prefix for?

Tags: c++, c++11

when I was reading `codecvt` example in [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), I noticed this line:

```
std::string data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(+u8"z\u00df\u6c34\U0001f34c");
```

Any idea what is that `+` before `u8` for? Because I removed it and nothing changed in result.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20439442/10871073

Comment: The sample on cppreference may have been written when an earlier C++ Standard was in use. I don't know, but maybe things have changed since C++11?

Comment: @AdrianMole I think problem starts from C++20 where `u8` is `char8_t`. then converting `char8_t[N]` from string literal will not be valid to `char*`. so it uses `+` to convert it to `char8_t*` first. Although compilers compile it with similar behavior, maybe it is UB without `+`.

Comment: ... in which case, the suggested duplicate is probably about right?

Comment: ... but I'm not *nearly* confident enough to hammer this one closed as a duplicate! (That hammer means - in theory - that I'm a C++ expert; however, it also means that I am careful about closing questions unilaterally!!)

Comment: @AdrianMole yea, you are probably right about duplicate in `+`. I don't mind if you flag it as duplicate for that thread. But for its usage here, I guess I don't delete the post(which I normally do).

Comment: Meh. It's a good question, and I'm really not *sure* that the dupe target actually answers why the cppreference folks added it ... as you have rightly said, removing it makes no difference in C++14, C++17 or C++20.

Comment: @AdrianMole removing `reinterpret_cast` break C++20 (because `char8_t` is not `char` starting C++20). So I think it is somehow related to use of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Afshin: _maybe it is UB without +_: I don't think so, if the argument to `reinterpret_cast` is an array it decays into a pointer before the conversion. Maybe it is "future-proof coding", so that if the C++-std decides to be able to `reinterpret_cast` an array directly without decay, then this code would still work because the `+` forces the decay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` is "explicitly" performing the array-to-pointer implicit conversion, producing a prvalue `const char8_t*` (or `const char*` before C++20), instead of an lvalue array.

This is unnecessary since `reinterpret_cast<T>` (when `T` is not a reference) performs this conversion anyways.

(Possibly it was used to prevent confusion with the similar `reinterpret_cast<const char* const&>(u8"...")`, which interprets the bytes of the array as a pointer, which is obviously not what was wanted. But I personally wouldn't worry about this)